# How to filter out footage into one clip

Tags: video, premiere, editing

The problem I am facing is I have too much of footage of which only 10% is going to be used for editing.

I don't want to store tons of footage which is not going to be used.

The most reasonable idea which comes to my mind is to run through all the footage, trim the bits ( which I would like to use in ONE or MORE future videos ) and save this trimmed compilation as a file for use in the future, 'open and pick up what I need' clip compilation file.

So the question is:

What would be the best approach to save space and time in filtering out the usable footage and getting rid of the footage that is never going to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Create a sequence with all assets that have not been used so far, but which you would like to keep. Next, use the Project Manager to export all relevant files to a new location (your archive) and have "Exclude unused Clips" checked. You may choose to do 2 exports: one with all the sequences for the main video except the extra sequence and another with only the extra assets sequence. When done, delete the original project folder.
2. Use a metadata attribute to mark which assets you do not want to keep. In the project panel, select list view and sort by that metadata column. Or you may move all the extra assets in other bins. For each bin select all the assets marked as unwanted and right click on Make Offline and select the delete option.

I think the first approach will be faster in most cases.

Comment: Thank you @Matt, rethinking this now, actually what I ideally want to do is to pickup few seconds of each footage and re render it as one file, so I can delete all the original footage. I will ask a separate question how to do it to not loose frames or quality when rerending.